# CSS/JS - How to make sure the line will break to be able to change the style?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am wondering if is there any way to know when a line will break, so I can use a different style.

Problem:
The design team want 3 buttons in a grid (3 columns) with a determined size.
When the content of the button breaks line they want I border-radius 13px while buttons that it's content is fit in one line will have border-radius:30px.

Solution with a problem:
My first solution was changing the class depending on number of characters, but it is not 100% perfect as we can see on the following images.

[(18 characters) should be border-radius:13px as it is breaking line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INEor.png)

[(19 characters) should be border=radius:30px as it is not breaking line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPk8T.png)

Question:
Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You may also fire a JS function on Page Load Complete to finalize the classes based on the element's calculated width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your help.
Some of the ideas here made me open my mind and I solved this problem.

Here is my solution:
As I am using react I wrote a useEffetc to include one more property to my array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const heights = itemRefs.current.map((itemRef) => itemRef.offsetHeight);
  setListOfHeights(heights);
  console.log(heights);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
 if (listOfHeights) {
  let shallowCopy = [...ingredients];
  shallowCopy = shallowCopy.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      height: listOfHeights[index]
    };
  });
  setListOfIngredients(shallowCopy);
 }
}, [listOfHeights]);
```

So I included a ref and a height condition inside my loop:

```
  <div className="ingredientsWrapper">
    {listOfIngredients.map((item, index) => (
      <div
      key={`item_${index}`}
        ref={(el) => (itemRefs.current[index] = el)}
        className={`ingredient ${item.height > 36 ? 'bigger' : ''}`}
        onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
      >
        {item.label}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```

Where 36 is my smallest height (so I know it represents no line breaks)

[Here is a codeSandBox with my solution](https://codesandbox.io/embed/polished-bird-medn1h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=light)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height of a single line button, you could theoretically [obtain the computed height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) of the buttons after the [page has fully loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), compare it, and then change the class accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use height of the div, like if the height is greater than 42px(height at which text will be in more than one line), then set border-radius to 20px else set it to 13px

```js
//jquery solution 
$(".div").each(function() {
  if ($(this).outerHeight() > 42) {
    $(this).css("border-radius", "20px");
  } else {
    $(this).css("border-radius", "13px");
  }
});

//pure javascript solution
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".div")).forEach((element, index) => {
  if (element.offsetHeight > 42) {
    element.style.borderRadius = "20px";
  } else {
    element.style.borderRadius = "13px";
  }
});

//use any one
```

```css
.div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  Lorem Ipsun dolor
</div>

<div class="div">
  Lorem <br/> Ipsum dolor
</div>
```

height depends upon your font (font-size, line-height, font-family) and padding.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey my suggestion would be,**

You should hard code it that when will the line break, *(eg : 20px/.5rem/ETC)*, and you can check how many letters can be there in that *20px/.5rem/ETC* area. If the length is more than what should be there, you perform a line break with Javascript (CSS), and change the border radius with Javascript (CSS).

There can be other solutions too. But Maybe it would work with some more work around.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can user RegEx to determine whether there is any line breaks in the button text.Then can add styles accordingly.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var btnValue = document.getElementById('btn').innerText;
     var lineCount = (btnValue.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
     if(lineCount > 0)
     {
        // Add Style Here
     }
    
    });
    </script>

    <body style="height:94%;" >
        <button id="btn">Lorem ipsum,
        <br>vero accusantium,
        <br>modi repellendus?
        <br>Enim nisi iusto.</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: The text is wrapping, it's not got actual line breaks.

Comment: On that case, height of the button is only differentiator here.So styling should be changed according to the height change of that button